# How to set up a heading before an output is printed in a for loop in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, python-2.7

I have 4 `df` in `list1`:

`df1`  `df2`   `df3`   `df4`

Each dataframe in `list1` goes inside a for loop and provides a single output, but before the output is printed i want a header to be given so that i can be able to identify to which group the output belongs to. i.e whether it belongs to high, low, medium or average

`list2` has all the headings that needs to be given for 4 outputs.
`list2 = ["High","Medium","Low","Average"]`

Example:

```
     Before df1 output is printed i wanted the heading to be 'High'

     Before df2 output is printed i wanted the heading to be 'Medium'

     Before df3 output is printed i want the heading to be printed as 'Low'

     Before df4 output is printed i want the heading to be printed as 'Average'
```

Below is my code:

```
import os
os.chdir(r'C:\Users\91979\Downloads\head code\src')
from classStruct.model import model
list1 = [df1,df2,df3,df4]
list2 = ["High","Medium","Low", "Average"]
for i in list1:
    needed_cols = i.columns
    target_col =  ['Rejection (%)']
    cols = list(set(needed_cols) - set(target_col))
    totData = i
    totData = totData.round(decimals=2)
    Model1 = model(totData,cols,['Rejection (%)'])
    clustSet = pd.DataFrame([C.clusterCenter for C in Model1.clustersList])
    Model1.predictor(clustSet, ["Rejection (%)"], Normalize=False)
    Model1.optimalClusterRejectionSeries = round(min(clustSet['Rejection (%)Predicted']),4)
    col_list = ['GCS (kg/cm2)', 'Inert Fines (%)', 'Volatile Matter (%)',
       'LOI (%)', 'Active Clay (%)', 'GFN/AFS (no)', 'Compactability (%)',
       'Wet Tensile Strength (gm/cm2)', 'Moisture (%)',
       'Permeability (no)', 'Temp. of Sand after mix.(C)']
    Model1.deNormalizeColumns(col_list, clustSet).to_csv("Predicted_optimal.csv")
    Model1.deNormalizeColumns(col_list, clustSet)

    
    for j in list2:
        print(j)
    print(pd.DataFrame(clustSet[clustSet['Rejection (%)Predicted'] == clustSet['Rejection (%)Predicted'].min()]))
    print('\n')
    print('\n')
```

In which part of the code should i print my headings in `list2` so that i get proper 4 iterations with correct headings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use zip:

```
list1 = [df1,df2,df3,df4]
list2 = ["High","Medium","Low", "Average"]
for i, j in zip(list1, list2):
    print('Before output is printed i wanted the heading to be %s' % j)
    print('This is the dataframe %s' % i)
```

And then you can print your dataframe `i` later in the loop after the header is printed.

sample header output:

```
Before output is printed i wanted the heading to be High
This is the data frame df1
Before output is printed i wanted the heading to be Medium
This is the data frame df2
Before output is printed i wanted the heading to be Low
This is the data frame df3
Before output is printed i wanted the heading to be Average
This is the data frame df4
```

Comment: thank you so much. It worked :) thanks for your time

Comment: @Thanuja You are welcome. A better way to thank on SO is upvote :)